# Alfresco community edition-5.1.x workflow task done user can't edit privious form

Tags: java, alfresco, alfresco-share

Alfresco community edition-5.1.x , We created custom workflow of sales order of product,First step get the order details from sales team fill the form  assign to operations team after assigned to the operations team sales team to get some more details from clients sales team wants to fill the details in the same task ,Is this possible ? and how?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Of course.

Workflows are meant to deal with all such processes.

You can create workflow with three different tasks

> **Sales Details-**-------> Will be assigned to Sales Team
>   **Operation Details**-->Will be assigned to Ops Team

You can create two different forms and while creating operation details form you can show all details filled previously by sales team.

- Create advance workflow in alfresco with those stages.
- Create Forms
  in alfresco and tag them with each task.

Comment: Problem is once sales team filled all the details click task done user can't  do edit right

Comment: Yes, If you want to allow Opes team to change that then you can show them those values as well.

Comment: May I know how can i give permission to change the values

Comment: Your both steps will be human steps, as I presume that there will be two different persons who will actually filling those information.

Comment: Actually starting process it self user filled form details i assigned to some users it will not assigned properly may i know how can use the form and what step i need to use the process